# how get rosjava?

Tags: ros, knowrobtutorials, knowrob, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi evey one :)
I don  not know how to get rosjava , I think I need it to solve a problem I have when try run mod_vis ?!!

Thanks in Advance,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46918/how-get-rosjava-?!/) by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 238 on 2012-10-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2012-10-27**:
I install rosjava from her but it is in my_workspace
http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/installing.html
, but still get the same error
http://answers.ros.org/question/46915/problem-in-knowrob/
so what is the the proposed solution ?!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are two versions of rosjave, one based on a JNI wrapper around roscpp and one native implementation written by Google. You can get the former one with

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-rosjava-jni
```

Note that when you already installed knowrob from debian packages (`sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-knowrob`), you will have it installed already.

For installing rosjava_core, follow the install instructions [here](http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/installing.html).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2012-10-28**:
yes I am already have ros-fuerte-knowrob and install rosjava from the same instruction in that link but I still have the same problem ?!!

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-28**:
Your question was just about how to install rosjava. You do not provide enough information about any other problem.

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2012-10-28**:
I do in a comment in the question !!

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-30**:
What exactly is the problem? Please be more specific and make sure you have a look at http://ros.org/wiki/Support